# Tool to launch a script driven by modem activity

Tags: security, script, modem

Can anyone suggest a software tool (preferably under Windows XP or later) that would launch an application or script in response to a phone call being received on a landline phone line connected to a data modem on the same PC?  or, better, in response to a sequence of touch-tones being played over such a phone line.  This would allow, for example, using the telephone to manipulate firewall settings so as to create another layer of security in connection with remote internet access to that computer.

I recall seeing tools to do this sort of thing in the days before broadband internet access, when there was more attention to various tips and tricks for the dial-up modem, but a few attempts at Google hasn't turned anything up.

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of a project I saw once.  I was looking for an answering machine program, and found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/IVR.aspx).  It isn't a working answering machine, but it claims to accept touch tone from the user.  I figured that maybe enough for you to trigger what you want.  I hadn't used this myself, and it is written in C++.  Hopefully it will at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like a good starting point if end up having to build my own.